# How to reload data table in one view, when we navigate back from another view?

Tags: javascript, view, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view page, where my data table load data, by clicking search button. In that table, there is an edit option, when I click the edit Icon,it takes me to another page to edit that selected row data. after editing, When I click Back button, it takes me to main view page,but table was cleared. For this, we need  to write code in document.ready(), but when we go from menu page,I dont want my table to load data before I click search button. 
My codes are:
 **for datatable in pay view:**

```
function Search() {
            if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#tblPay' ) ) {
      $( '#tblPay' ).DataTable().destroy();
        }
         var txtVal = $("#txtDescription").val();
            $('#tblPay' ).DataTable({  
               "searchable": false,
                "ajax": {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetValues")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { txtVal },
                    dataSrc: 'data',
                },
                "columns": [{ data: "Id" },
                { data: "Description" },
                {
                          "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                          { return '<a class="text-center" href="/Master/Details/' + full.Id + '"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'; }
                    },
                   {
                          "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                          { return '<a class="text-center" href="/Master/Edit/' + full.Id + '"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>'; }
                      },               
                   {
                           data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                               return '<a href="#"  onclick=DeleteData("' + row.Id + '"); ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                           }
                       },               
                ]
            });
        }
```

**My Edit page javascript to save data:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function Save() {
        var txtVal = $("#txtId").val();
         var txtVal1 = $("#txtDescription").val();
        if (txtVal1 == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Description!");
        }
        else {
             var url = "/Master/EditSave";

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        data: {txtVal,txtVal1},
                        cache: false,
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (result) {
                   if (result.success == 'success') {
                 alert(result.message);
             }
            else {
                 alert(result.message);
            }
        }
                          });
                         $('input[type="text"]').val("");
            }
    }
    </script>
```

**The 2 buttons in my edit Page-save and back:**

```
 <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a id="btnSave" onclick="Save()" name="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Save</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="/Master/Pay" id="btnBack" name="btnBack" class="btn btn-block bg-purple btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Back </span><i class="fa fa-step-backward "></i></a>
                                </div>
```

Is there any way to reload datatable in pay page when I only navigate back from edit page?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a datatable which directs you to another page when you click a row/cell in the datatable.

A simple solution to tell your datatable page to load table XYZ (whatever it needs to) would be to direct the user back to that page from your edit page with a URL parameter like so `www.example.com/index.php?reload`.

In your Javascript entry point (document load for example), you would put the following

```
urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (urlParams.has('reload')){
    //your datatable reload code
}
```

Comment: ur understanding is absolutely correct. this code to be added in data table view page or in navigated view page? As I tried in Datatable document.ready function, it nevere works for me

Comment: @Riya Which ever page your datatable resides on would be where you add that code as the parameter will be added on to the end of the URL by the edit page when redirecting back so, `example.com/index.php` -> `example.com/edit.php` -> `example.com/index.php?reload`